# Saving Gridview Data To Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am having a Gridview which i want to save in my another table

My Code is

```
protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Pre_Y1_Bus1 (CRITICAL,SPECIFICATION, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],TMLCAL) VALUES (@CRITICAL, @SPECIFICATION, @[1], @[2], @[3], @[4], @[5], @TMLCAL)";

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRITICAL", row.Cells[0].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPECIFICATION", row.Cells[1].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[1]", row.Cells[2].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[2]", row.Cells[3].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[3]", row.Cells[4].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[4]", row.Cells[5].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[5]", row.Cells[6].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TMLCAL",row.Cells[7].ToString());
         con.Open(); //here i am having an respected error
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
         Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }

    }
}
```

My error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
help me to resolve this

Comment: which line did u face this exception? add try/catch block

Comment: use like Cells[1].Text.ToString().

Comment: I would try something like `row.Cells[7]?.ToString() ?? System.DbNull.Value` or as yekanchi said but I would include null propagation as well.

Comment: not working for my code , will you please help me with some another code

Answer (score 0):

Replace .ToString() with Convert.ToString as shown below. It will handle blank as well as null value. Then you can check why the value is coming null. You also need to add .Text as shown below.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRITICAL", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPECIFICATION", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `.ToString()` make sure that your object is not null, Also to read cell text you must put `.Text` 
Something like this :

```
    if (row.Cells[0] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[0].Text)) {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRITICAL", row.Cells[0].Text.ToString());

    } else {
     // Handle it
    }
```